# how to use java or c# interface in c++ using pure virtual functions in base abstract classes

Tags: c++

I want to use interface in C++ which can be used in C# or Java. I've read some articles and inspected some source codes that summarily say i should use pure virtual function in abstract classes but i still could now got the point well.

How can i change the function behavior at run time using pure virtual function? Should my variable be at base with classes type?

For example below code (from tutorialspoint) is written with java and uses Strategy design pattern using interface.

Strategy.java

```
public interface Strategy {
   public int doOperation(int num1, int num2);
}
```

OperationAdd.java

```
public class OperationAdd implements Strategy{
   @Override
   public int doOperation(int num1, int num2) {
      return num1 + num2;
   }
}
```

OperationSubstract.java

```
public class OperationSubstract implements Strategy{
   @Override
   public int doOperation(int num1, int num2) {
      return num1 - num2;
   }
}
```

OperationMultiply.java

```
public class OperationMultiply implements Strategy{
   @Override
   public int doOperation(int num1, int num2) {
      return num1 * num2;
   }
}
```

Context.java

```
public class Context {
   private Strategy strategy;

   public Context(Strategy strategy){
      this.strategy = strategy;
   }

   public int executeStrategy(int num1, int num2){
      return strategy.doOperation(num1, num2);
   }
}
```

StrategyPatternDemo.java

```
public class StrategyPatternDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Context context = new Context(new OperationAdd());        
      System.out.println("10 + 5 = " + context.executeStrategy(10,     5));

      context = new Context(new OperationSubstract());      
      System.out.println("10 - 5 = " + context.executeStrategy(10, 5));

      context = new Context(new OperationMultiply());       
      System.out.println("10 * 5 = " + context.executeStrategy(10, 5));
   }
}
```

Above changing behavior of the function is made using following code line

```
context = new Context(new OperationMultiply());
```

How can i make it with C++ using pure virtual function and how can i change method behavior?

is it possible using pure virtual functions in the same way with java interfaces?

Regards

Comment: *"I want to use interface in C++ which can be used in C# or Java."* - Do you mean "which can be used *like* in C# or Java"?

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: By the way, your `Context` class looks like an unnecessary additional layer whose only purpose is to create complexity.

Comment: Context class is not unnecessary. The whole code is a sample implementation of Strategy Design Pattern.

Comment: I understood C++ usage by inspecting the sample code in the link. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy/cpp/1

Comment: @mehmetrizaoz any luck with this?